# Вывести атрибуты и элементы из XML в MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

Есть переменная с xml-документом.

```
DECLARE @docxml xml;
SET @docxml='<Root>
                <Order>
                <Items>
                    <Product ProductID="1" ProductName="Book1" ProductCategory="A">
                        <Price val="RUB" PValue="300"/>
                        <Autors lang="русский">
                            <Autor>
                            Автор1
                            </Autor>
                            <Autor>
                            Автор2
                            </Autor>
                        </Autors>
                        <Features>
                        <Description>Описание товара Book1</Description>
                        <Garant>3 года</Garant>
                        </Features>
                    </Product>
                    <Product ProductID="2" ProductName="Book2" ProductCategory="F">
                        <Price val="DOL" PValue="50"/>
                        <Autors lang="английский">
                            <Autor>
                            Autor1
                            </Autor>
                            <Autor>
                            Autor1
                            </Autor>
                        </Autors>
                        <Features>
                        <Description>Описание товара Book2</Description>
                        <Garant>1 год</Garant>
                        </Features>
                    </Product>
                    <Product ProductID="3" ProductName="Book3" ProductCategory="A">
                        <Price val="RUB" PValue="700"/>
                        <Autors lang="русский">
                            <Autor>
                            Автор3
                            </Autor>
                            <Autor>
                            Автор4
                            </Autor>
                        </Autors>
                        <Features>
                        <Description>Описание товара Book3</Description>
                        <Garant>2 года</Garant>
                        </Features>
                    </Product>
                </Items>
                </Order>
                <Order>
                <Items>
                    <Product ProductID="4" ProductName="Book4" ProductCategory="A">
                        <Price val="RUB" PValue="900"/>
                        <Autors lang="русский">
                            <Autor>
                            Автор5
                            </Autor>
                        </Autors>
                        <Features>
                        <Garant>3 года</Garant>
                        </Features>
                    </Product>
                </Items>
                </Order>
            </Root>';
```

Необходимо вывести все атрибуты и элементы ProductID, Price и Autor

Делаю так:

```
DECLARE @docxml xml;
SET @docxml='<Root>
                <Order>
                <Items>
                    <Product ProductID="1" ProductName="Book1" ProductCategory="A">
                        <Price val="RUB" PValue="300"/>
                        <Autors lang="русский">
                            <Autor>
                            Автор1
                            </Autor>
                            <Autor>
                            Автор2
                            </Autor>
                        </Autors>
                        <Features>
                        <Description>Описание товара Book1</Description>
                        <Garant>3 года</Garant>
                        </Features>
                    </Product>
                    <Product ProductID="2" ProductName="Book2" ProductCategory="F">
                        <Price val="DOL" PValue="50"/>
                        <Autors lang="английский">
                            <Autor>
                            Autor1
                            </Autor>
                            <Autor>
                            Autor1
                            </Autor>
                        </Autors>
                        <Features>
                        <Description>Описание товара Book2</Description>
                        <Garant>1 год</Garant>
                        </Features>
                    </Product>
                    <Product ProductID="3" ProductName="Book3" ProductCategory="A">
                        <Price val="RUB" PValue="700"/>
                        <Autors lang="русский">
                            <Autor>
                            Автор3
                            </Autor>
                            <Autor>
                            Автор4
                            </Autor>
                        </Autors>
                        <Features>
                        <Description>Описание товара Book3</Description>
                        <Garant>2 года</Garant>
                        </Features>
                    </Product>
                </Items>
                </Order>
                <Order>
                <Items>
                    <Product ProductID="4" ProductName="Book4" ProductCategory="A">
                        <Price val="RUB" PValue="900"/>
                        <Autors lang="русский">
                            <Autor>
                            Автор5
                            </Autor>
                        </Autors>
                        <Features>
                        <Garant>3 года</Garant>
                        </Features>
                    </Product>
                </Items>
                </Order>
            </Root>';

CREATE TABLE txml (fx xml);
INSERT INTO txml (fx) VALUES (@docxml);
SELECT  T.C.value('../../@ProductID', 'int') AS ProductID,
        T.C.value('../../Price/@PValue', 'int') AS Price,
        T.C.value('text()[1]','varchar(15)') AS Autors
        
FROM txml a CROSS APPLY
            a.fx.nodes('/Root[1]/Order/Items/Product/Autors/Autor') AS T(C);
```

Не выводит Price, остальное если без Price делать, то выводит

Comment: Вы можете привести sql-код, который можно скопировать и сразу выполнить?

Comment: Через FROM OPENXML я реализовал вывод ProductID, Price и Autor. А вот выше код что-то Price не выводится

Comment: добавил код выше

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте к вопросу ожидаемый результат на основе примера данных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно использовать `Price[1]` и ваш запрос заработает.

Я бы строил путь от общего родительского элемента, которым является `Product`.

```
SELECT  
  T.C.value('@ProductID', 'int') AS ProductID,
  T.C.value('Price[1]/@PValue', 'int') AS Price,
  T.C.value('Autors[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS Autors
        
FROM txml a CROSS APPLY
  a.fx.nodes('/Root[1]/Order/Items/Product') AS T(C);
```

В узле `Autors` может быть несколько значений `Autor`. Нужно получить их все или только первый? И т. к. там русский текст, то используем `nvarchar`.

В вашем варианте возвращается семь строк, по общему количеству авторов. В моём - 4 строки, по количеству продуктов (авторы при этом объединены).

---

Как объединить атрибуты `PValue` и `val`?

Вариант с функцией `concat` T-SQL:

```
concat(T.C.value('Price[1]/@PValue', 'int'), ' ', T.C.value('Price[1]/@val', 'varchar(3)')) AS Price1,
```

Вариант с функцией `concat` xquery:

```
T.C.query('text{concat(Price[1]/@PValue, " ", Price[1]/@val)}').value('.', 'varchar(15)') as Price2,
```

Comment: Спасибо! 
И еще вопрос: можно при выводе как-то объединить в один столбец Price атрибуты PValue и val?
Или все таки их надо по отдельности выводить?

Comment: @monah - обновил ответ

Answer (score 1):

Пожалуйста, попробуйте следующее решение.

Примечательные моменты:

- Валюта получила свой собственный столбец.
- Столбец авторов показывает всех авторов.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (fx xml);
INSERT INTO @tbl (fx) VALUES
(N'<Root>
    <Order>
        <Items>
            <Product ProductID="1" ProductName="Book1" ProductCategory="A">
                <Price val="RUB" PValue="300"/>
                <Autors lang="русский">
                    <Autor>Автор1</Autor>
                    <Autor>Автор2</Autor>
                </Autors>
                <Features>
                    <Description>Описание товара Book1</Description>
                    <Garant>3 года</Garant>
                </Features>
            </Product>
            <Product ProductID="2" ProductName="Book2" ProductCategory="F">
                <Price val="DOL" PValue="50"/>
                <Autors lang="английский">
                    <Autor>Autor1</Autor>
                    <Autor>Autor1</Autor>
                </Autors>
                <Features>
                    <Description>Описание товара Book2</Description>
                    <Garant>1 год</Garant>
                </Features>
            </Product>
            <Product ProductID="3" ProductName="Book3" ProductCategory="A">
                <Price val="RUB" PValue="700"/>
                <Autors lang="русский">
                    <Autor>Автор3</Autor>
                    <Autor>Автор4</Autor>
                </Autors>
                <Features>
                    <Description>Описание товара Book3</Description>
                    <Garant>2 года</Garant>
                </Features>
            </Product>
        </Items>
    </Order>
    <Order>
        <Items>
            <Product ProductID="4" ProductName="Book4" ProductCategory="A">
                <Price val="RUB" PValue="900"/>
                <Autors lang="русский">
                    <Autor>Автор5</Autor>
                </Autors>
                <Features>
                    <Garant>3 года</Garant>
                </Features>
            </Product>
        </Items>
    </Order>
</Root>');

SELECT c.value('@ProductID', 'INT') AS ProductID,
     c.value('(Price/@val)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(10)') AS Currency,
     c.value('(Price/@PValue)[1]', 'INT') AS Price,
     c.query('data(Autors/Autor)').value('. cast as xs:token?', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Authors
FROM @tbl
    CROSS APPLY fx.nodes('/Root/Order/Items/Product') AS t(c);
```

**Результат**

| ProductID | Currency | Price | Authors |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | RUB | 300 | Автор1 Автор2 |
| 2 | DOL | 50 | Autor1 Autor1 |
| 3 | RUB | 700 | Автор3 Автор4 |
| 4 | RUB | 900 | Автор5 |